# PC turns on for 20 seconds, but then restarts

Tags: desktop-computer

I have been having a problem where my *PC turns on for about 20 seconds*, but then restarts. *The pc doesn't connect to a monitor*, and I have a backlit keyboard that I  connected to it, but the keyboard doesn't light up when it is on. *It used to restart every 3 seconds, but I moved a ram card to a different slot*, and now it is doing this. I have vacuumed out the pc, and it didn't change anything. *The thermal paste on the cpu was old and dried out*, so I don't know if it is working properly. *I have tried unplugging all the unnecessary components*, and it still doesn't work. I don't know if this is a power supply problem. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @dandavis the light on the power button turns off, and the fans turn off. Then a few seconds later the light on the power button turns on, and the fans turn on again.

Comment: It could be a mobo problem, but I suspect the power supply is going out. Does it smell chemically or burny around the fan? A lot of times, the capacitors in them dry out and they fail in interesting ways. Based on the dried heatsink compound, i'm guessing the power supply is more than 5 years old. If you're handy with a multi-meter you can test it apart from the mobo, or in-situ, looking for accurate 3.3, 5, and 12v regulation. I'm sure there's some youtubes on the procedure. If it checks out, mobo is bad, if not, get a new one, but it's one of the few diags you can do w/o a 2nd system.

Comment: @dandavis there are no smells as far as I can tell. By the way, does a computer have to have a hard drive to run? It might have been the hard drive.

Comment: you should see video regardless of the hard drive, unless it totally fried and shorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you removed unnecessary components, or maybe just remove the RAM completly, does the system give/gave beeps code ? If no I would think it's a bad motherboard first.

If unsure for the powersupply you can test out with a multimeter but it can be hard to do. A small video link on the howto [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr70VyoACPg). It exist some tool to test the powersupply, as some led will show if all the voltage are correct.

Comment: To test for a beep code do I need to plug in a speaker?

Comment: @Spencer1O1 the beep will come from the built-in speaker inside your computer case, not a speaker plugged from an audiocard

Comment: From what I can hear, the system is not giving beep codes. I can hear something in the disc drive moving, but the disc drive functions properly. It is pretty much the only thing that works properly on the computer.

Comment: Is it possible that the CPU is overheating because it doesn't have sufficient thermal paste?

Comment: you can diagnose the heat sink as follows. keep the pc off for 15 mins. feel the heatsink, pay attention to how warm it is, a thermometer is helpful.  turn it on and run until it restarts, then power off. Immediately check the temp, as you turn it off. If the temp goes higher for more than a few seconds before it creeps back down you have poor conduction, and the CPU is harboring lot of thermal energy.

Comment: @dandavis I remember I turned the computer on and let it restart, but then I took off the fan and felt the cpu and it was hot. I will quickly test the heat sink